# Issues with transaction name and operation in Sentry for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sentry, apm

I'm using Sentry on a big Laravel site and have an issue which is impacting my ability to diagnose performance issues.

Operations seem to be incorrectly split across the frontend and backend views in the Performance dashboard. For example, I'd expect the backend to show `queue.process` and `http.server` and frontend to show `pageload` and `navigation` - but in reality both views are showing the same set of aggregated transactions. I also have some jobs showing up as both `(empty string)` and `queue.process` (with the exact same event ids in each).

I'm using a 'standard' installation as per the docs - just letting the out-of-the-box package pull the config from `config/sentry.php` (for the backend) and passing in the dsn, sample rate etc to the sentry js sdk.

Using v3.8.0 of the `sentry/sentry-laravel` composer package and v7.41.0 of `sentry/browser` and `sentry/tracing` npm packages.